# Emacs after-make-frame-functions argument is void

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacsclient

I have the following code in my `.emacs` file. It's supposed to move the input focus to any newly created frame.

```
(defun foo-focus-new-frame (frame)
  (select-frame-set-input-focus (frame)))
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'foo-focus-new-frame t)
```

This works fine when I run emacs directly from the command line. However, if emacs is not started and I try and run the following:

```bash
emacsclient -c -a '' test.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
*ERROR*: Symbol's function definition is void: frame
```

Why is this? According to the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Frames.html) the `after-make-frame-functions` hook should only be run after a frame is newly created, so why can't my function find it?

Comment: I think you'll find that it fails in *exactly* the same way when you run Emacs normally (bearing in mind that the initial frame is created before your custom code is ever evaluated). Try `C-x 5 2` to create a *new* frame.

Comment: @phils, you are indeed correct. My mistake. It was just more obvious when running emacsclient (since it refused to start at all) than when running Emacs normally (since the error was only displayed in the `*Messages*` buffer, but everything still ran as normal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `frame` function doesn't exist, perhaps you intended to access the parameter instead of calling a function, i.e. you have extraneous parentheses in `foo-focus-new-frame`:

```
(defun foo-focus-new-frame (frame)
  (select-frame-set-input-focus frame))
```

Comment: Thank very much! I feel dumb for missing this - still working my way up the Lisp learning curve.